# Understanding Promise constructor

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm new to Promises and I'm trying to understand the Promise constructor. According to [promisejs.org](https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/), something which is maybe a promise can be resolved using `Promise.resolve`, e.g.

```
var maybePromise = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 10 : Promise.resolve(10);
var definitelyPromise = Promise.resolve(maybePromise);
```

`Promise.resolve` is equivalent to (**case1**):

```
var definitelyPromise = new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
  if (isPromise(maybePromise)) {
    maybePromise.then(fulfill, reject);
  } else {
    fulfill(maybePromise);
  }
});
```

I wonder if this is also equivalent to (**case2**):

```
var definitelyPromise3 = new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
  if (maybePromise instanceof Promise) {
    fulfill(maybePromise);
  } else {
    fulfill(maybePromise);
  }
});
```

(Of course the `if...else...` can be removed, because I call `fulfill(maybePromise)` in both cases).

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sv8dobdz/1/)

Comment: It depends on what `isPromise` function does. `maybePromise instanceof Promise` only checks whether `maybePromise` is instance of `Promise` constructor, while `isPromise` could check whether `maybePromise` is any then-able.

Comment: Michał, the sample in promisejs.org uses a `isPromise`, but I don't know where this function is implemented or how to implement on my own. Could you please give me a sample demonstrating different behaviour of case1 and case2 if an arbitrary then-able is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the first argument of the promise constructor callback is called `resolve`, not `fulfill`.

When you pass a [promise or thenable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29437927/1048572) into `resolve`, its state will get adopted, all other values [fulfill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29268569/1048572) the promise directly. This means that exactly the logic you were describing is implemented right within `resolve` - and, as you said, you don't need the condition in the resolver callback.

And in fact, the [standard specifies `Promise.resolve`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.resolve) to be implemented quite like

```
function resolve(x) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(x);
    });
}
```

Comment: This means case1 and case2 are both correct implementations and behave exactly the same way? Btw: I used `fulfill` instead of `resolve` because the sample is copied from promisejs.org

Comment: @krombi: It depends on what `isPromise` does whether case 1 is behaving in *exactly* the same way, but in general the idea is correct.

Comment: Damn, in my question I used `isPromise` from jspromise.org for case1, but in my jsfiddle I use `if (maybePromise instanceof Promise)` in both cases...