# Why can't I use Promise.resolve with an osmosis instance?

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise, console.log

**I am trying to understand why these `console.log` statements behave differently. I expect them to behave the same:**

Using Node 7. Consider the following cases:

**1. Promise.resolve(object)**

`Promise.resolve` handles objects as I'd expect:

```
Promise.resolve({ a: `hello` }).then(console.log) // { a:'hello' }
```

**2. Directly `console.log` a class instance from a library.**

If I store an Osmosis instance I can console.log it:

```
const osmosis = require(`osmosis`)
console.log(new osmosis.get(url)) 
/* { prev:                                                                                                                                                                   
     { instance: Osmosis:1,                                                                                                                                                 
     name: 'get',                                                                                                                                                         
     args: [ 'http://www.google.com', ,  ],                                                                                                                               
     getURL: [Function: getURLArg],                                                                                                                                       
     url: 'http://www.google.com',                                                                                                                                        
     params: undefined,                                                                                                                                                   
     cb: [Function: Get],                                                                                                                                                 
     next: [Circular] } }
*/
```

**3. Promise.resolve(class instance)**

But if I try to resolve an Osmosis instance I don't see parity:

```
Promise.resolve(new osmosis.get(url)).then(console.log) // nothing
```

What's going on here? Am I misunderstanding something about `Promise.resolve()`...? Or `console.log`?

### Why doesn't [3] log the same as [2], given the behavior in [1]?

**Context**: I don't think my immediate practical goals matter to answering this question. But here you go just in case. I don't see how anything about the library itself should affect the output of the final example. Here's the docs on that `new osmosis.get()` though: http://rchipka.github.io/node-osmosis/Osmosis.html#toc1__anchor

`new osmosis.get(url)` doesn't perform an async http request. It instantiates an instance of the scraper, which can be built up with a set of declarative instructions and told to "run" at some arbitrary later time.

I want to be able to build this set of instructions in a promise chain for several reasons.

The main one is that it would be the easiest way to break up the instruction definitions into different functions that are easier to test and understand. e.g. instead of `osmosis.get(url).set({some stuff}).find(@something)`, I'd like to:

```
function defineSearch(instance){
  return instance.set({some stuff})
}

function definePath(instance) {
  return instance.find(@something)
}

Promise.resolve(new osmosis.get(url))
  .then(defineSearch)
  .then(definePath)
  .then(instance => instance.run())
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish by wrapping an object in `Promise.resolve()`?  If you're hoping it will wait until some async operation is done, that is not how promises work.  In this case, wrapping your operation in `Promise.resolve()` is not really helping you in any way.

Comment: I've add some context above, if it helps. But in the case of this question I am literally only trying to understand why that console.log prints empty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum but why can I directly `console.log` a new instance, but never see the instance passed on via `Promise.resolve`? It's not a question of callbacks. I have direct, immediate, synchronous access to the `new osmosis` instance outside the `Promise.resolve` context.

Comment: Just in case... *catch* the call to `osmosis`... maybe `osmosis.get` is throwing an exception so does not reach the `then()` clausule

Comment: @Manu that's no longer an issue with node. It will log unhandled rejections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is horrible and uses techniques that are rather unconventional. What `new osmosis.get(url)` returns is not an [`Osmosis`](http://rchipka.github.io/node-osmosis/Osmosis.html) instance but a [`Command`](http://rchipka.github.io/node-osmosis/Command.html) one. And those do have a [`then` method](http://rchipka.github.io/node-osmosis/Command.html#then__anchor).

When you pass something to `Promise.resolve`, it is tested for being a [thenable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29437927/1048572) or not, and if it looks like a promise it is tried to be assimilated: a callback is passed into the `then` method which will resolve the new promise.

So when you do `Promise.resolve(new osmosis.get(url))`, you get back an unresolved promise that will fulfill when the `then` callback is called (which happens when you run the command). In your case, it never does.

The solution to your particular problem is not to use promises at all (since you're not doing anything asynchronous):

```
definePath(defineSearch(new osmosis.get(url))).run())
```

but you probably should also report a bug that `Command`s look like promises with being properly thenable, which breaks a lot of things in ES6.

Comment: Yes, the duck-typing bug is what I wasn't seeing. You're right that I cant just pass the instance through a series of functions, but it looks like like garbage and I was hoping to avoid it. It's true that I am not in fact doing anything asyncronous, but the promise chain naturally describes what it intuitively seems is happening when the scraper starts (just without actually starting it).

Thanks a lot! (yeah those docs are drek)

Comment: For proof this answer is correct:

    const x = new osmosis();
    x.then = null;
    Promise.resolve(x).then(console.log) // everything works