# Javascript Class - Chaining async methods and returning "this"

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm attempting to introduce a queue-type system to a JS class to allow for Async method chaining, ideally, I'd like to perform operations on the class instance using these async methods and return "this" instance.

```
export class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this.queue = Promise.resolve()
        this.firstRequestStarted = false
        this.firstRequestStatusCode  = 0
        this.secondRequestStarted = false
        this.secondRequestStatusCode = 0
    }
    then(callback) {
        callback(this.queue)
    }
    chain(callback) {
        return this.queue = this.queue.then(callback)
    }
    first() {
        this.chain(async () => {
            try {
                this.firstRequestStarted = true
                const response = await axios.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")
                this.firstRequestStatusCode = response.status
                return this
            }
            catch (e) {
                const { message = "" } = e || {}
                return Promise.reject({ message })
            }
        })
        return this
    }
    second() {
        this.chain(async () => {
            try {
                this.secondRequestStarted = true
                const response = await axios.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
                this.secondRequestStatusCode = response.status
                return this
            }
            catch (e) {
                const { message = "" } = e || {}
                return Promise.reject({ message })
            }
        })
        return this
    }
}
```

Functions are added to the queue, and as we await them, the "then" method will handle their execution.

```
const x = await new Queue()
            .first()
            .second()
        console.log(x)
```

The challenge I'm facing is that I can never actually get "this" (instance of Queue) back to x.

```
1) x === undefined
2) "Chaining cycle detected for promise #<Promise>"
or ( I haven't been able to track down where this one is coming from, node error)
3) finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

I have tried adding a "consume" method, which simply returns "this", this leads to error #2 above

```
me() {
        this.chain( () => {
            try {
                return this
            }
            catch (e) {
                const { message = "" } = e || {}
                return Promise.reject({ message })
            }
        })
        return this
    }
```

The confusion on my part, is that if I use any value other than "this", it works as expected

```
me() {
        this.chain( () => {
            try {
                return "test"
            }
            catch (e) {
                const { message = "" } = e || {}
                return Promise.reject({ message })
            }
        })
        return this
    }
```

`x === "test"`
I'm also able to return the values associated to this with something like the following
`return {...this}`

Ideally, I'd like to return the instance of Queue to X, as I plan on modifying the properties of the Queue instance through my async methods, await them, and be returned with an "initialized" instance of Queue.

Any input would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async/Await Class Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor)

Comment: What is your actual use case? It seems like one would always call `.first()`, then `.second()`? Is the order really arbitrary, are repetitions allowed? Why do you need to use chaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Queue` instances are thenable (have a `.then()` method), and the promise is tried to be resolved with itself (`this.queue`). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57878723/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40716155/1048572).

You have two options:

- Do not resolve your promise with the instance, but write

  ```
  const x = new Queue().first().second();
  await x;
  console.log(x);
  ```
- remove the `then` method from your class, then call

  ```
  const x = new Queue().first().second().queue;
  console.log(x);
  ```

  (or possibly introduce a getter method - `.get()`, `.toPromise()` - instead of directly accessing `.queue`)