# promise-like objects and then-able duck typing in javascript promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm currently learning the javascript `promise`.

I have been taught that if an object/function contain a member function named `then(..)` on itself, then the object/function will be recognised as a `promise like object`, regardless whether the object/function is a true promise object or not.

So I have come up with the following code.

```
var aPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject){});
aPromise instanceof Promise; //prints true in chrome console


var a = {
    then: function(){}
};

a instanceof Promise;
```

But after `a instanceof Promise` is executed in chrome console, `false` was printed.

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong or my understanding of what is a promise-like object is incorrect?

Comment: “Promise-like object” means that despite it *not* being the case that `a instanceof Promise`, `a` can be treated like a promise.

Comment: I think what it means is that it will act like a promise, but is not necessarily an instance of it. As in it behaves like one, but is still literally just an Object.

Comment: `it will act like a promise` - hopefully, because there's no guarantee that a `.then` function has to do anything promise like :p

Comment: please correct me if I'm wrong, but my current understanding is that `a instance Promise` by itself it enough to determine whether a object is a real `Promise` object (i.e. return `true` for objects that are true `Promise` object) or a `Promise-like object` (i.e. return `false` for objects that has a `then` function on it, and can be used as a promise object, but is not a true Promise object)

Comment: anything not a Promise will result in `a instance Promise` being false ... even those without a `.then` ... `instanceof` does not care about thenables

Comment: thanks everyone for the clarification! now everything starts to make sense :)

Comment: instanceof as the name implies tests if an object is an instance of some constructor function. Since your `a` was not created by the Promise constructor function, nor a function that inherited from it then it is not an instance of it. If you wanted to test "promise like" or "thenable" then test for `then`, `if('then' in a)`

Comment: I never thought of duck-typing as "ducking type" before but thats an interesting take on it :)

Comment: Have a look at [what is the difference between the terms “thenable” and “promise”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29435262/1048572) and maybe also [decide if object or promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43033988/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A. `instanceof`

Technically, the Javascript expression `a instanceof b` checks

- `a` is an object (which includes functions because they are objects),
- 'b' is a constructor function - which includes classes because declarations and expressions using the `class` keyword create constructor functions,
- the value of `b.prototype` is in the inheritance chain of `a`. This means either `a` was constructed by `b`, or otherwise somewhere in the inheritance chain of `a` there is an object constructed by `b`.

Given an objects inheritance chain is set to the `prototype` property of its constructor, `aPromise` in your code is an instance of `Promise` because `Promise.prototype` is the first entry in its prototype chain. The second entry in its prototype chain is `Object.prototype` so `aPromise` is an instance of `Object` as well.

`a` is constructed and initialized by `Object` in response to the `{..}` object initializer syntax. `Object.prototype` is the first object in its inheritance so its an "instance of" `Object` and nothing else.

### B. Thenable objects

"Thenable" objects, with a `.then` method, are described in the [A+ promise specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) on which ES6 promises are based.

Recognition and treatment of thenables allow different software libraries, each using its own Promise constructor code, to deal with promises created by another library created using a different constructor.  Simply checking if a promise object is an instance of a library's own "Promise" constructor prevents inter-library usage of promise objects.

The one time a promise implementation needs to deal with a "thenable" object, is when a foreign library promise is used to resolve a promise created by an implementation. The standard method of dealing with this is for the implementation to create a new pair of resolve/reject functions, say `resolve2` and `reject2` for the promise being resolved, and call the thenable's `then` method to pass on it's settled value. In pseudo code:

```
if promiseA, instance of PromiseA, is resolved with promiseB, instance of PromiseB {

    PromiseA code creates new resolve2/reject2 functions for promiseA
    and calls the thenable's then method as:

         promiseB.then( resolve2, reject2);
}
// ....
If promiseB remains pending, promiseA remains pending;
If promiseB is settled, promiseA becomes fulfilled or rejected with the same value.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the method **Promise.resolve** to convert your thenable object ('a') into a Promise:

```
var a = Promise.resolve({
    then: function(){}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object in its prototype chain
>   has the prototype property of a constructor.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

This is unrelated to (maybe even the opposite of?) duck typing, wherein an object's methods and properties determine the *symantics* of the object, thereby allowing you to *treat* it like you might treat a `Promise`, but it in no way makes it an instance of or descendant of a `Promise`.

(*emphasis added by me*)

> In computer programming with object-oriented programming languages,
>   duck typing is a style of typing in which an object's methods and
>   properties determine the valid semantics, **rather than its
>   inheritance from a particular class or implementation of a specific
>   interface**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing via https://ericlippert.com/2014/01/02/what-is-duck-typing/

A concrete example in javascript is the `nodeList`; it is array-like because you can access members of a node list by an integer index, but it is not an array, nor an `instanceof` an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for a thenable (Promise like) object

```
if ((typeof a === 'function' || typeof a === 'object') && typeof a.then === 'function') {
    // a is "Promise like" (or a Promise)
}
```