# Race conditions using Office.js in Excel

Tags: javascript, async-await, office-js

I'm encountering some sort of race condition in the following code where I'm trying to write the response of an HTTP request to the active cell. I've read some possible solutions to the "InvalidObjectPath" errors from Office.js (I'm using ScriptLab specifically), but I don't think I'm trying to use anything across multiple contexts.

The current behavior works sometimes, but other times nothing will get written to the cell.

```
var counter = 0;
$("#run").click(run);
async function run() {
    try {

        await Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
            var user; 
            const sUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange(); 
            counter++;
            client.get(sUrl, function (response) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                user = obj.username;
                range.values = [[user + counter]];
                ctx.sync();
            });
            await ctx.sync();
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}

var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
        anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're not awaiting the completion of `client.get`.  This means that [some of the time], the `Excel.run` will complete and "garbage-collect"(ish) some of the objects (`range`) before the callback inside of `client.get` is executed.

You can solve the issue in a number of ways:

1. Do the call to the web service before you execute the `Excel.run`.  In your example here (which may not be realistic for many other scenarios, but it is here), you're not actually relying on anything from the document at all before you do your web call.  In that case, no need to be inside the `Excel.run` at all, you can have `Excel.run` be part of the callback on the web service call.
2. Wrap your web-service call in a Promise, so that it can be awaited.  Something like this: 
   `var HttpClient = function() {
       this.get = function(aUrl) {
           return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
               var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
               anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                   if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200) {
                       resolve(anHttpRequest.responseText);
                   } else {
                       reject(anHttpRequest.statusText);
                   }
               }
               anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
               anHttpRequest.send(null);
           });
       }
   }`

I describe both approaches (and much more...) in a book that I've been writing about Building Office Add-ins using Office.js: https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/.  I'm pasting in a few screenshots below from some of the relevant book content.

BTW, I should say that getting the selection is one of the few times when you don't want to delay a `sync`, as you want to capture the fleeting point-in-time selection rather than what will become the selection X seconds from now, once the web call succeeds.  So this is one of the few cases where you may want to insert an extra `await context.sync()` even if you don't technically need it.  See section "*5.8.2: When to sync*" in the book for more info.

=====

**Promisifying an API**:

[image: Promisifying an API]

=====

**From about Promises**:

[image: From about Promises]

=====

**From the implementation details section:**

[image: From the implementation-details section]

Comment: Could you provide those excerpts as quoted text instead of paintings, please?

Comment: You don't need to (and should not) use the `new Promise` constructor for "promisifying" the jQuery ajax call. Just do `return Promise.resolve($.ajax(…)).then(…, …)` - jQuery already returns a thenable (you could even `await` the jQuery deferred directly)

Comment: @Bergi, screenshots are easiest for me, since the book is authored in a dialect-ish of Markdown (`Markua`) that is used by LeanPub, but doesn't always play 100% well with GitHub.

Comment: @Bergi, for promisifying a jQuery ajax call:  it's true that jQuery returns a promise, though unfortunately it's not a fully-standard Promise (e.g., it doesn't have a ".catch").  So I think there is still value in wrappnig it with a standard Promise for greater flexibility, especially when I want to
do some post-processing on the server response, like I did above.  However, that same chapter also has other examples, such as Promisify-ing the setTimeout function.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Thank you! I'll ultimately want to use the value from getActiveRange() to build the request URL, so I'll be Promis-ifying the the web-service call.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Yes, wrapping it is a good thing, but you should `Promise.resolve` instead of `new Promise` for that. Your snippet is essentially using the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) - and lacks error handling for the code inside the `done` and `fail` callbacks.

Comment: @Bergi, perhaps I'm just misunderstanding it -- but even in the constructor antipattern link that you sent, I see things like "You should only use deferred objects when you are converting an API to promises and can't do it automatically, or when you're writing aggregation functions that are easier expressed this way.".  Of what I have seen/read about the jQuery Promise object, because it isn't a fully standard Promise (i.e., doesn't support `.catch`), it seems safest to treat it as if it's a non-promiseful API, and wrap it in a Promise constructor.  Happy to learn more if you disagree.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft It doesn't need to support catch. It doesn't even need to feature a `then` that returns a new promise. It only needs to be [thenable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29437927/1048572) and call the respective callback, and you can pass it to `Promise.resolve(…)` to *get* a fully standard promise. And even when you want to wrap it in a promise constructor, you should wrap it *directly* (`new Promise((res, rej) => $.ajax(…).then(res, rej))` or `….done(res).fail(rej)`), instead of doing a bunch of stuff in those non-standard unsafe `done` and `fail` callbacks.