# Custom thenables: Can I create my own objects with a "then" method?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm wondering if custom "thenables" (aka an object with a `.then()` method) are approved/documented?  How do they compare to real Promises?  I suppose it matters how you implement then, so I'm wondering if there's documentation with some DOs and DONTs.

[This page](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) suggests:

> .then may return an arbitrary “thenable” object, and it will be treated the same way as a promise.

Can't find any docs on this.

Comment: `I suppose it matters how you implement then` indeed it does - as for documentation ... maybe the .then description in the "spec" https://promisesaplus.com/

Comment: I'll have to study that link, thank you.  I'm hoping to find some more thorough examples of how to implement your own custom thenables.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "approved"?

Comment: Even if a custom .then-able works in some cases, it might fail in others, if it's not a "real" promise, for example.  That's why I was wondering if custom thenables were "best practice", or an intended feature.  I would think that creating custom .then-ables has a lot of potential, and there would be lots of people doing it.  And there would be specific patterns/anti-patterns.

Comment: @MikeLewis What potential do you see that is not covered by simply creating a "real" promise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do thenables compare to real Promises?

In that you don't know whether they are real promises or not. Have a look at [Regarding Promises/A+ Specification, what is the difference between the terms "thenable" and "promise"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29435262/1048572).

> I'm wondering if there's documentation with some DOs and DONTs about how to implement them (as that seems to be what matters)

There's the (pretty simple) [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) that documents how thenables are treated. ES6 promises (and by extension, `await`) follow this. Basically:

- your object has a property with the name `then` whose value is a function
- the function will get called with two callbacks
- you can call either of them - asynchronously or not
- the first call determines what happens to the promise that assimilated your thenable

It's really no magic. You call the first argument when you want to resolve with a value, and you call the second argument when you want to reject. There are no DONTs assuming a proper promise implementation - you can call the callbacks as often as you want, and keep them around as long as you want: the calls should be ignored and the reference should not leak memory.

Comment: That last part seems a little wonky.  So I await my custom thenable, potentially in a loop or something.  Potentially 1000 times per second (I don't have a real use case, just what-if-ing here), and each time, it gives me a new cb.  If I'm using a typical callback pattern (array of functions), then I'm storing 1000s' of callbacks, calling *all* of them each time my streamy.thenable emits data...?

Comment: You're saying, it doesn't matter if I call those already-called callbacks again, it shouldn't hurt anything.  But, in the case that there are a lot of them... doesn't seem to be a great idea.

Comment: @MikeLewis Actually an `await` in a loop will suspend the loop until the value is resolved :-) Yes, piling up callbacks is not a great idea. Of course it still hurts to do many useless operations, and to keep useless stuff in memory; all I'm saying is that it does not affect the promises that were resolved with the thenable.

Comment: What about chaining?  A custom thenable's `.then()` method should return a new thenable, with a `.then()` method, that's somehow linked to the return value of the function passed to the first one.  I think?  Not sure how that applies to repeatable thenables (like events/streams)

Comment: No. The return value of `then()` is discarded when it is assimilated by a promise (or `await`). Chaining only matters when you want to work with thenables yourself - but then really there's no good reason not to just use a proper promise.