# Why does 'await' trigger '.then()' on a Proxy returned by an 'async' function ?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-promise, es6-proxy

I am compiling the code with babel (env), compiling down to ES5.

Here's the code:

```js
(async () => {
     const p = async () => {
          return new Proxy({}, {
               get: (target, property) => {
                    console.log(property);
               }
          })
     };

     const r = await p();// await calls .then on the result of p()
})();
```

Comment: It is not because of `await`. This happens if `p` is invoked.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the Proxy just helped to see this behaviour ! Calling an async causes '.then()' to be called on the return / result. So if the return result it's an Object, .then() will be called on it. It seems that this behaviour is used to cascade nested promises. What now ? How can we avoid this behaviour ? I blacklisted '.then' inside of my Proxy, but it's not the best. @thefourtheye

Comment: @Pirix Why would you want to avoid it? This is how promises and async functions work. What's the purpose of your proxy in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi
The async function causes to call .then() on it's result / return (if it's an Object). This should only happen when returning an async/promise.

Comment: @Pirix And how do you think the async function knows that you are `return`ing an "async/promise"?

Comment: @Bergi with an instanceof Promise. I don't see anywhere in the specs that an **async** function must call **.then()** on it's return value. And I see that **await** must resolve the result / return of a **promise/async**.
So yes it resolves the result but calls .then() on it

Comment: `await` is supposed to be used on a *thenable*, it makes no sense to "await" something else, so your function needs to always return a promise. Calling `.then` is what *resolving the result* means. It's not `async` the calls `.then`, it's `await` that does it in order to get the resolved value.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm the _thenable_ is the async function itself. So I await the result of  it which is my proxy.

Comment: No, the *thenable* is what your async function returns. `await` interprets your proxy as a wrapped thenable and resolves that as well. If it didn't do that, it wouldn't be compatible with promises

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually happening twice.

> Why is `.then()` triggered on a Proxy returned by an `async function`?

The result of an `async function` call is a promise that is *resolved* with the `return` value from the function body evaluation. Resolving a promise checks whether the resolution value is a [thenable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29435262/1048572) ("promise-like value"), which would lead to the promise waiting for the inner result. (In your case, accessing `.then` on the proxy does not return a function, so it's not considered a thenable and the promise is fulfilled with the proxy).

> Why does `await` trigger `.then()` on a Proxy?

Same here. `await` does not work only with promises, it works on arbitrary values. To determine their "promise-worthiness", it runs exactly the same thenable check - it resolves a promise with the awaited value and then waits for the promise to settle.