# Why is matchAll for RegExp in JavaScript so different than other methods?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript has a regular expression class `RegExp`. You can create them directly `re = new RegExp(...)` or indirectly `re = /.../`

Most of the traditional methods are what I'm used to from many years of programming

```
const match = re.match(str);
const isMatch = re.text(str);
```

But today I looked for a matchAll function and to use it the syntax is this

```
const matches = re[Symbol.matchAll](str)
```

What's up with this style of finding a function? Why is it not just

```
const matches = re.matchAll(str);
```

I'm guessing there is some reason there are a several functions using this special format. What is the reasoning behind it?

```js
const re = /a(.)b(.)c/g;
const matches = re[Symbol.matchAll]('a1b2c a3b4c a5b6c');
console.log([...matches]);
```

Comment: When adding new facilities to JavaScript, the committee has to be careful not to break half the Internet. Old pages may have added `String.prototype` methods (it was common 10 years ago and may still be) and thus name collisions would make working pages fail with new browser releases.

Comment: Because there's no practical way to *ensure* that new features do not introduce name collisions. The `Symbol` class is designed explicitly to address that, you can add all the random Symbol instances you want, and they're guaranteed to be distinct from any other instance.

Comment: Right but no legacy page would be doing that, since the `Symbol` facility itself is new. New code that tried that would be "born" facing the fact that it's stepping on a built-in facility.

Comment: lol, embarrassing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I looked for a matchAll function and to use it the syntax is `re[Symbol.matchAll](str)`

No. The proper syntax is to use the [String `matchAll` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll), like this:

```
const matches = str.matchAll(re);
```

> What is the reasoning behind several functions using this special format?

They are following a *protocol*. Like the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) or the [thenable protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29437927/1048572), they are usually used internally in some other methods/syntax and are not supposed to be called directly. Such a protocol allows for customised implementations of the feature, providing a hook to override.

In the case of [`Symbol.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/matchAll), it allows arbitrary objects to be used as matchers for strings. For example:

```js
const integers = {
    *[Symbol.matchAll] (str) {
         for (const m of str.matchAll(/\d+/g))
             yield parseInt(m[0], 10);
    }
};

console.log(Array.from("42ab17, 2x".matchAll(integers)))
```

The `matchAll` and `match` symbols were introduced to allow a `class` that `extends RegExp` to override the behaviour when interacting with the respective `String` methods. In practice, the inheritance relationship is not enforced though, the mere existence of the symbol-keyed method is enough.

Comment: well color me pink

Comment: /setColor [ pink, target=@Pointy ]

Comment: I am however a *little* surprised at adding a `String.prototype` method after almost 20 years of the Wild West.

Comment: Does that mean [the MDN docs for String.matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) are out of date? They don't mention `matchAll` taking anything but a `RegExp` at least as of 2019-06-23

Comment: @gman I'd rather say *incomplete*, not "out of date", since it doesn't mention this ability. However, the `matchAll` Symbol is indeed meant to be mostly placed on RegExp objects, it specifically was introduced to allow overriding `String::matchAll` behaviour for `RegExp` subclasses.

Comment: @Bergi What syntax are you using to colour Pointy pink? I don't recognise it. I would have done something like `#Pointy { color: pink; }` :P

Comment: @Clonkex i guess some mix of IRC, Minecraft and Discord commands