# JS Promises: does the then() method always return a promise, or can it return a thenable?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm reading [this article](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) about Promise chaining, and it says "`a handler may return not exactly a promise, but a so-called “thenable” object`". I want to know which of the following is correct:

1) The handler can return a promise or a then-able object, but the `then()` method containing the handler must return a promise.

2) The handler can return a promise or a then-able object, and the `then()` method containing the handler can also return either a promise or a then-able object.

Comment: A thenable's `.then()` method need not return either a Promise or another thenable, but the utility of such a thenable would be severely limited. It could only be used at the end of a chain.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I understand that a custom thenable's then() method doesn't have to return a promise or another thenable. What I'm wondering is for a Promise (not a custom thenable), is it the then() method or the then() method's handler that has the option to return either a promise or a custom thenable?

Comment: If you are asking about Promises, then the answer is simple, [then must return a promise](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-40). Hence, the question is only worth asking if it is about arbitrary thenables, not Promises.

Comment: Got it, thanks! If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @Bergi's answer says it all. You may accept his answer. The poor boy needs the points :-)

Comment: @Roamer-1888 didn't realize you were being sarcastic until I looked at his score. Guy doesn't mess around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a [promise](https://promisesaplus.com/) unless [its `.then(…)` method returns a promise](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-40), and if it's an ES6 native `Promise` then it definitely will.

A [thenable's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29435262/1048572) `then` method may return anything (including `undefined`).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! See @Roamer-1888's savage last comment above.