# Why am I getting an unexpected behavior in my implementation of Promise.race()?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the code for my Promise.race() implementation, *and it basically works*. However, in this case:

```
promiseRace([Promise.reject('test_error'), Promise.resolve('test_value')])
```

I am getting `test_value` instead of `test_error`.
Why it happens?

```js
const promiseRace = promises => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  promises.forEach(p => {
    if (
      typeof p === 'object'
          && 'then' in p
          && typeof p.then === 'function'
    ) {
      p.then(resolve).catch(reject);
    } else {
      resolve(p);
    }
  });
});

promiseRace([Promise.reject('test_error'),
  Promise.resolve('test_value')]).then(value => { console.log(value); });
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think the result should be `test_error`? I know `Promise.race` results in `test_error`, but why do you think _your_ code should do this too? Walk us through your reasoning behind what each line in your function is meant to do, so that folks can point out where your assumptions don't match with how JS has been designed to work. Also, note that you don't need that big if statement, `if (p instanceof Promise)` is all you need. Also note you're not concerned with preserving "`this`", so writing this as a normal `function promiseRace(promises) { ... }` would be fine.

Comment: This option is less beautiful, however, if we are talking about two tabs (yes, in this case instanceof is justified), then there will be problems with instanceof, because if you pass code from one tab to another - there are different Promise objects

Comment: That doesn't matter? If it's a promise, `p instanceof Promise` is true, the end. Whether you pass code around or not makes no difference: anything that's a promise, is a promise, and thus is an instance of the `Promise` object type.

Comment: Instead of doing the thenable check yourself, just call `Promise.resolve(p)`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans "*anything that's a promise, is a promise, and thus is an instance of the `Promise` object type.*" - [not quite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29435262/1048572), no.

Comment: @Bergi fair enough. Is there a prototype symbol that's easy to check at least? (like for Iterables)? Because this shouldn't require duck-typing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans There would be - if promises weren't predating symbols :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because in the following line, you call `.catch` on another (chained) promise, not on the original promise:

```
  p.then(resolve).catch(reject);
```

Note how the `then` call does not get a `reject` callback argument, and so there is an extra -- intermediate asynchronous promise cycle. By the time the `.catch` callback is called (`reject`), the other case has already been dealt with (the fulfulled promise).

So change to:

```
  p.then(resolve, reject);
```